# Авто переключение блоков js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

есть код , он переключает блоки по нажатию кнопок , нужно что бы помимо нажатий блоки сами переключались через какой то промежуток времени.

```js
    var btn = document.querySelectorAll('#p1'),
     three = document.querySelectorAll('.three')[0];
     for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
      btn[i].addEventListener('click',function() {
       three.className = 'three';
       three.classList.add('three-' + i);
      })
     }
```

```css
    {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #272727;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .one {
      width: 400px;
      height: 100px;
      background: green;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .two {
      display: inline-block;
      align-content: space-between;
      width: 50px;
      height: 100px;
      background: #272727;
      z-index: 5;
    }
    
    .three {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      flex-direction: row;
      width: 350px;
      height: 100px;
      background: red;
      transition: transform .3s;
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    
    .three-0 {
      transition: transform .3s;
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    
    .three-1 {
      transition: transform .3s;
      transform: translateX(-350px);
    }
    
    .three-2 {
      transition: transform .3s;
      transform: translateX(-700px);
    }
    
    .three-3 {
      transition: transform .3s;
      transform: translateX(-1050px);
    }
    
    .four {
      min-width: 350px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
   <p id="p1" style="margin-top: 5px; cursor: pointer; background: #cd1; text-align: center;">1</p>
   <p id="p1" style="margin-top: 5px; cursor: pointer; background: #1cd; text-align: center;">2</p>
   <p id="p1" style="margin-top: 5px; cursor: pointer; background: #11d; text-align: center;">3</p>
   <p id="p1" style="margin-top: 5px; cursor: pointer; background: #d0e; text-align: center;">4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="three three-0">
   <div class="four" style="background: #cd1; text-align: center;">11</div>
   <div class="four" style="background: #1cd; text-align: center;">22</div>
   <div class="four" style="background: #11d; text-align: center;">33</div>
   <div class="four" style="background: #d0e; text-align: center;">44</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если взять уже имеющийся цикл и добавить setTimeout то происходит задержка на определенное время и переключения с первого на последний блок сразу (всего их 4)

```
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
        (setTimeout( function() {
            three.className = 'three';
            three.classList.add('three-' + i);
        },1000))
    }
```

Comment: не хотите ли свой html привести?

Comment: да что то не подумал , добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы такие элементы списком сделал,как сделать пример ниже,думаю будет понятно:

html:

```
<ul>
  <li class="active">1 блок</li>
  <li>2 блок</li>
  <li>3 блок</li>
</ul>
<style>
  .active {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

js:

```
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = ul.querySelectorAll("li");

ul.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    li.forEach(function(item) {
        item.classList.toggle('active',false);
    });
    evt.target.classList.toggle('active');
});
setInterval(function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++){
            if(li[i].classList.contains('active')){
                li[i].classList.remove('active');
                if(i+1 < li.length) {
                    li[++i].classList.add('active'); return;
                }
                else {
                    li[0].classList.add('active');
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Работает , но как сделать теперь слайдер из div'ов , что бы например написано по списку 1 блок , и отображается  1 блок отдельно, переключением появляется новый ? Получается нужно сделать пару дивов , сделать им класс если active то display block если нет то none ? JS плохо знаю , тут получается нужно еще переменные добавить и в цикле еще дописать условие для отображение diva ?

Comment: в css заранее прописать стили, например ul > li { display: none; } ul > .active { display: block;}, но лучше все делать через классы