# Обратная анимация на чистом JavaScript в слайдере

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии по слайду вперед, анимация начиналась ни с первого слайда а с текущего.(так же при кнопке назад).
Когда мы доходим до последнего слайда и нажимаем вперед, должен выезжать первый слайдер.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("picture");
  var mySlides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  console.log(slides.length);
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }
  if (n == 1) {
    var t = 0;
  }
  if (n == 2) {
    var t = 1
  }
  if (n == 3) {
    var t = 2
  }

  function animate(options) {

    var start = performance.now();

    requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
      // timeFraction от 0 до 1
      var timeFraction = (time - start) / options.duration;
      if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;

      // текущее состояние анимации
      var progress = options.timing(timeFraction)

      options.draw(progress);

      if (timeFraction < 1) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }

    });
  }
  animate({
    duration: 2000,
    timing: function(timeFraction) {
      return timeFraction;
    },
    draw: function(progress) {
      mySlides[0].style.marginLeft = progress * (-1000) * t + 'px';
    }
  });
  console.log(slideIndex);
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";

}
```

```css
.slidershow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 350px;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.next {
  right: 8px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.mySlides {
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 700px;
  width: 3000px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 505px;
}

.picture {
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  float: left;
}

img {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 350px;
}

.numbertext {
  display: inline;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slidershow-container">
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="picture"><img style="background-color: black;" src=""></div>
      <div class="picture"><img style="background-color: #ff4b5a;" src=""></div>
      <div class="picture"><img style="background-color: #36ff31;" src=""></div>
    </div>
    <a onclick="plusSlides(-1)" class="prev">&#10094</a>
    <a onclick="plusSlides(1)" class="next">&#10095</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>

  </div>
  <div class="div"></div>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755718/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-js/755741#755741